# Get all numbers from an integer array?

Tags: java, arrays

How would i go upon getting all the numbers in a declared array, then get the length, meaning how many numbers in it, then divide by that to find the average of all the numbers in it.

```
package students;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class students {

private ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private String name;
    private int testScore;

    public students(){
        name = null;
        testScore = 0;
    }

    public students(String s, int t){
        name = s;
        testScore = t;
    }

    public void addQuiz(int t){
        scores.add(t);
    }

    public void averageGrade(){
        //get all the scores in the array and divide by the amount for average grade
    }
}
```

Theres my code

Comment: Why not try to code it?

Comment: This is meant to be a simply assignment, but i dont want the code to be too long. So i wanted to just add all the scores that are added to an array, then just get all of them, i could code it but i was just wondering if there is an easier way

Comment: You should show us your attempt first, then others can help you correct your mistakes or show you more efficient ways of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void averageGrade() {

    int sum = 0;
    float average = 0.0f;


    for(int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++)
        sum += scores.get(i);       // Compute total score

    average = (float)sum / scores.size();  // Compute average

    System.out.println(average);
}
```

Comment: Watch out for integer division.

Comment: An average is usually not an integer.

Comment: What would be the difference between sing a float and a double?

Comment: A float occupies less space than double. But double gives you more accurate result. You can go with double if you prefer accuracy over memory usage

Comment: Ahh makes sense then, Memory usage isnt a big deal, this is a small program. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 8 there is a Method for calculating an average:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html#getAverage--

And the respective Integer version can be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html#getAverage--

Comment: Interesting to know, thank you, but probably not a valid answer for an `int[]`.

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, just noticed that by myself a second before ;) Added the link to the Integer version as well.